Finding a conjugacy between two polynomials.
I assume finding a conjugacy requires finding a homeomorphism between $f(x) = x^2 - 2$ and $g(x) = 4x - 4x^2$. I know this has to be a function $h(x)$ that is bijective, continuous, and has a continuous derivative. I tried working with shifts of $x$ to get something like $(c_1 x + c_0)^2 = 2 + 4x - 4x^2$, but this leads to a series of equations that cannot all be fulfilled:
$$(c_1 x + c_0)^2 = c_1^2 x^2 + 2c_0 c_1 x + c_0^2 = -4x^2 + 4x + 2 \implies \begin{cases} c_1^2 = -4 \implies c_1 = \pm 2i \\\ c_0^2 = 2 \implies c_0 = \pm \sqrt{2} \\\ 2 c_0 c_1 = 4 \implies c_0 c_1 = 2 \end{cases}$$ which cannot all be true, as an imaginary number times a real one will not yield a real number.
Any ideas on how else to go about this? Is there a general process to follow when finding homeomorphisms between two functions other than guessing and checking? What conditions would guarantee a homeomorphism does not exist?

When you say 'I assume the question requires', what question are you referring to?

The question in the title. I'm asked to find a conjugacy between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and looking at the definition of a conjugacy I got that that means a homeomorphism.

Your definition is actually slightly incorrect. Your calculations are looking for an $h()$ with $f(h(x))=g(x)$, but for two functions to be conjugate the correct condition is $f(h(x))=h(g(x))$, or $f(x)=h\circ g\circ h^{-1}(x)$. If you think about the dynamics, this makes a good deal more sense: if $g=f\circ h$ then $g(g(x))=f(h(f(h(x))))$ isn't generally the same as $f(f(h(x))$, but if $g=h^{-1}\circ f\circ h$ then $(g\circ g)(x) = (h^{-1}\circ f\circ h\circ h^{-1}\circ f\circ h)(x)$ $=(h^{-1}\circ f\circ f\circ h)(x)$; in other words, $g\circ g$ and $f\circ f$ are also conjugate. Plugging in this definition to your original question goes a lot more smoothly: we're trying to solve $f(c_0x+c_1)=c_0g(x)+c_1$...
$$\begin{align}
f(c_0x+c_1) &= (c_0x+c_1)^2-2 \\
&=c_0^2x^2+2c_0c_1x+c_1^2-2 \\
c_0g(x)+c_1 &= c_0(-4x^2+4x)+c_1 \\
&= -4c_0x^2+4c_0x+c_1
\end{align}$$
Comparing leading coefficients shows that $c_0^2=-4c_0$, i.e. $c_0=-4$; you should be able to find $c_1$ almost as easily.

Yes, I saw that. I must have made a silly mistake somewhere along the way. Solving for $c_1$, I got that $c_1 = 2$. Since $h(x)$ is allowed to be any homeomorphism, is the rule to just try as many general forms as possible until one works? An immense thank you for your help, Steven.

Generally if you're explicitly asked to find such a conjugation, it will be linear and so you can do something along these lines. There are non-linear conjugations — the most famous and important is probably between the logistic map $x_{n+1} = 4x_n{1-x_n}$ on $[0, 1]$ and the bit-shift $y_{n+1} = (2y_n)\bmod 1$ — but finding them explicitly is an incredibly non-trivial task.
